# Querying multiple joined inherited tables filtered by a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy scheme that looks roughly like this:

```
participation = db.Table('participation',
        db.Column('artist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'),
                  primary_key=True),
        db.Column('song_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('song.id'),
                  primary_key=True),
)

class Streamable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    kind = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': kind}

class Artist(Streamable):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('streamable.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(128), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'artist'}

class Song(Streamable):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('streamable.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(128), nullable=False)
    artists = db.relationship("Artist", secondary=participation,
                              backref=db.backref('songs'))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'song'}

class Video(Streamable):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('streamable.id'), primary_key=True)
    song_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('song.id'), nullable=False)
    song = db.relationship('Song', backref=db.backref('videos', lazy='dynamic'),
                           primaryjoin="Song.id==Video.song_id")
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'video'}
```

I'd like to do a single query for Songs or Videos that have a particular artist; i.e., these two queries in one query (all queries should be `.order_by(Streamable.score)`):

```
q1=Streamable.query.with_polymorphic(Video)
q1.join(Video.song, participation, Artist).filter(Artist.id==1)
q2=Streamable.query.with_polymorphic(Song)
q2.join(participation, Artist).filter(Artist.id==1)
```

Here's the best I reached; it emits monstrous SQL and always yields empty results (not sure why):

```
p1=db.aliased(participation)
p2=db.aliased(participation)
a1=db.aliased(Artist)
a2=db.aliased(Artist)
q=Streamable.query.with_polymorphic((Video, Song))
q=q.join(p1, a1).join(Video.song, p2, a2)
q.filter(db.or_((a1.id==1), (a2.id==1))).order_by('score')
```

What's the right way to do this query, if at all (maybe a relational datastore is not the right tool for my job...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are basically right. I think the change from `join` to `outerjoin` should solve the problem:

```
q=q.outerjoin(p1, a1).outerjoin(Video.song, p2, a2)
```

I would also replace the `order_by` with:

```
q = q.order_by(Streamable.score)
```

Comment: Switching to outerjoin makes the query return songs, but no videos. Querying only for videos by artist with id==1 does work.

Comment: strange, my sample code found both... Could it be because your sample code has `a2.id==2` instead of `a2.id==1`?

Comment: That typo was indeed embarrassing, but it wasn't that. Even after I fixed it, I still get only songs. I verified again that my separate queries (the middle code block in my original question) actually do return videos by artist 1 and songs by artist 1. Also, I edited the original question to remove the typo (`a2.id==1`) so as not to confuse people. I'm willing to share my scheme from `pg_dump` if that could help... Any other ideas?

Comment: ok. check the code at http://snipt.org/waaab1. If you run the script, it returns one Video and one Song...

Comment: How extremely comprehensive of you, thank you very much! I'm still not sure why, but as I was playing with the answer and trying to understand what was wrong I recreated my database scheme and recreated the data from the sample data I have, and the problem went away. I guess something was wrong with the scheme or data I had, but certainly the `outerjoin`s are what made the important difference. Thanks again!